# Method to update data in GUI and deliver parameter

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am puzzled when encounter the problem as I handling my project.
The following code is a abstract version. By the way, I am sad but I have to handle in that way~~

**Main entry and frame**

```
package com.ryougi.repaint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class RepaintTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()-> {
            JFrame frame = new TableFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class TableFrame extends JFrame {

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private String data = "Old Data";

    public TableFrame() {
        setTitle("TableFrame Frame");
        setSize(960, 540);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initLayout();
    }

    public void initLayout() {
        button = new JButton("Add");
        label = new JLabel("Old Data");
        scrollPane = MyModule.MyScrollPane(data);

        // Style of scrollPane
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 960, 360);
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        // Style of button
        button.setBounds(420, 400, 120, 40);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        // Listener of button
        button.addMouseListener(new BtnClickListener(this));

        add(scrollPane);
        add(button);
    }

    public JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public void setScrollPane(JScrollPane scrollPane) {
        this.scrollPane = scrollPane;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Self-design module**

```
package com.ryougi.repaint;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MyModule {
    private static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private static JLabel label;

    public static JScrollPane MyScrollPane(String data) {
        label = new JLabel(data);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);
        return scrollPane;
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
package com.ryougi.repaint; 
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BtnClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private String data = "New Data";
    private JFrame frame;

    public BtnClickListener(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        // ((TableFrame) frame).setData(data);
        ((TableFrame) frame).setScrollPane(MyModule.MyScrollPane(data));
        ((TableFrame) frame).getScrollPane().repaint();
    }
}
```

I want to repaint the `scrollPanel` to refresh the text show on the `label`, that means from `Old Data` to `New Data`. But I failed to change it by calling

```
((TableFrame) frame).setScrollPane(MyModule.MyScrollPane(data));
((TableFrame) frame).getScrollPane().repaint();
```

Can Anybody provide me some advise? Thank you.
What should I do to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setScrollPane(JScrollPane scrollPane) {
    this.scrollPane = scrollPane;
}
```

This will set your scrollPane attribute to the given scrollPane. Which is great, except it has nothing to do with the JFrame anymore.

In the beginning, you actually add your scrollPane to your JFrame. But you never remove it and exchange it with the new one. You just change what scrollPane your attribute refers to. Repainting that might be fun, but won't show because that new scrollPane wasn't added to the JFrame to begin with.

Edit:
You are making your life way too complicated with the way you programmed it when all you really want is change out a label text... just add the following method to your TableFrame class:

```
public void updateLabelText(String newText) {
    label.setText(newText);
    label.repaint();
}
```

Then you can just call

```
((TableFrame) frame).updateLabelText(data);
```

from your MouseListener and you won't even need the MyModule class at all...

I think your main problem is that you don't understand the difference between references and the actual object.

Comment: Thanks, What should I do to achieve my purpose?

Comment: I'm having technical problems right now but I'm in the process of updating my answer, give me a moment :D

Comment: Thanks your anwser first. The way you show is workable, But I am handing a project need lots of self-define module. This instance is a simple one I simplify the problem in my project. I need to use a self-define module. Making this as a prerequisite, is there other method to solve it? In my project I would like to deliver a ResultSet.

Comment: That depends on what the specific requirements for your module are. You could create a method in your TableFrame class that will return the current label and then just give the label as a parameter to your module, so your module can do what the updateLabelText method in my example does.

Comment: If you don't want to give the label to the module... well... i just don't see the point of the module at the moment to be honest, so it's difficult for me to understand what else you could need your module to do.

Comment: If you actually need to switch out the scroll pane and label every time you change the label text (which I feel is a bad way of going about it in the first place), you would need to actually remove the old scrollpane from the jframe, then add the new scrollpane to it.

Comment: OK, giving me some time to sort my question out. I will discuss it in detail.

Comment: I had thought about the problem in detail last night, actually I believed that the way I used be a stupid way, I had suggested my boss to change a simple method. Thanks a lot. Have a good day.